# Can I conditionally start the Visual Studio debugger, without adding extra code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, loops, conditional-statements

I guess the answer is 'no', but I decided to ask you guys :)

So, imagine i have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Let's say I've put a breakpoint inside VS on the line where the first curly brace is ("{"). I can go through all iterations of the for loop one by one, but imagine I'm interested in a particular one, for example, the 700th one. The only intuitive way I can think of is to remove this breakpoint and put one inside a code snippet that goes like:

```
if (i == 700)
{
    // Add a breakpoint here.
}
```

So, my question is whether there is a better way to achieve this task? :)

Comment: @rene it *is* the feature that is needed, but to find that question, you need to know the feature exists and how it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional breakpoints and set the condition to `i==700`.

See "[How to set conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670415/how-to-set-conditional-breakpoints-in-visual-studio)"